# Recommended way to add a key-value-pair given as tuple to a dict?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

It feels like I'm just missing the obvious but.. how do I add a value to a `dict` if I'm given a key-value-tuple?

```
def foo():
    # magic
    return key, value

d = {}
d.update((foo(),))
```

Isn't there something like `d.add(foot())`?

I hope I'm just in need of some coffee..

Comment: What? With your score you should know [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You could set a good example and tell me what exactly your problem with my question.

Answer (score 0):

this works but I don't know this is recommended.

```
d.update(dict([foo()]))
```